# Compile a statically linked executable of the "stress-ng" package

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries

I'm trying to compile the "stress-ng" package to produce a statically linked executable to use it inside GEM5 full system simulator.

A tarball of this package can be downloaded [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/tarballs/stress-ng/). The version I'm trying to compile is 0.07.08.

To compile a dynamically linked executable of this package, just "make". This works for me.

However, since I need to run the "stress-ng" exe from within a GEM5 full system simulation, I need to make sure that the exe is self-contained. This is usually done using the "-static" CFLAG option, however, for "stress-ng", I get an error when I try this option.

Here is what to do in order to reproduce this error. Edit "Makefile" and add "-static" option at the end of line # 25. Line 25 should look like the following:

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -DVERSION='"$(VERSION)"' -O2 -std=gnu99 -static
```

Save then make, you will see the error below:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(lowlevellock.o): In function `__lll_lock_wait_private':
/build/eglibc-3GlaMS/eglibc-2.19/nptl/../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:78: multiple definition of `__lll_lock_wait_private'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(libc-lowlevellock.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(lowlevellock.o): In function `__lll_unlock_wake_private':
/build/eglibc-3GlaMS/eglibc-2.19/nptl/../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:328: multiple definition of `__lll_unlock_wake_private'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(libc-lowlevellock.o):(.text+0x30): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [stress-ng] Error 1
```

Finally, OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and cc version is 4.6.4.

Am I missing some other CFLAG option(s) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've pushed a new fix to the stress-ng repo that now allows static linking. The issue was that -lc was before -lpthread, which caused the problem.

Pull the latest changes and then build with:

STATIC=1 make

Comment: You are the developer of this tool, aren't you? Thanks a lot for helping man. I have one more question please: Is there any issue or limitation preventing the usage of stress-ng in a gem5 simulated system? I'm asking because when I tried stress-ng (with options "--cpu 4 -b 1 --vm 4 --vm-bytes 1M --timeout 4s") from within a simulated system, I got an error, which luckily did not stop the execution of the workers, but I'm not sure how serious the error is. The error says "stress-ng: error: [46] /sys/devices/system/cpu does not exist". Any idea please?